# How to have selected columns (based on column header) fill down to the last row of the sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a script to fill down values of the column based on the column header/first value of the column. In this case, I want the script to identify all columns with the header "||" and fill down to the current region of the sheet.

I have the following but instead of filling down on all columns I want just columns with "||" in the header. Can a condition be a added in thewith statements? Or is there a better approach?

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
Option Explicit


On Error Resume Next


With Columns
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).formula = "=R[-1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With
Err.Clear
End Sub
```

Screenshot of spreadsheet: Imgur: The most awesome images on the Internet

Also, the || columns varies. Sometimes there could be 3, other times it could be 6+

Comment: Loop through all columns and check for header.

Comment: Or you could use the find and findnext on the first row.

Comment: Option Explicit is not used ***inside*** a procedure, but at the top of the module. Also, as you've been asked before, please indent your code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub FillCellsFromAbove()
Dim lColumn As Long, yes As Integer

lColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lColumn
    yes = InStr(Cells(1, i).Value, "||")

    If yes <> "0" Then
        'Add code to fill in the column
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, adapted your code and it's working so far.

```
For i = 1 To lColumn
    yes = InStr(Cells(1, i).Value, "||")
    If yes <> 0 Then
    Set Filldown = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lrc, i))
    Filldown.Select
    Selection.Filldown
    End If
Next i
```